# Find the string is XML or JSON or String using angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, angular, pretty-print

I need to find my string is XML or JSON object or string, based on this response I will make the string looks pretty.

So for that, I need to identify what kind of object. Can anyone please help me to find a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: validation , what is meaning , you want to find out which type of object or you want to find its xml, or json or string

Comment: Yes Pranay Rana, I want to find out its xml, or json or string.

Comment: can you post your response string

Comment: Corrected my question

Comment: you should try to parse string to xml if succeed then it's xml then try to parse in json if succeed then it's json else it's  string.

Comment: 1. ["{"timestamp":"2018-05-15 17:25:02","message":"Requ…NotSupportedException","path":"/service//CANCEL"}"] 2.<RRTransaction xsi:schemaLocation="urn:vnnm.CASMO.com/Schemas/RRParms RRParms.xsd" xmlns="urn:vnm.CASMO.com/Schemas/RRParms" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"; xmlns:xsi1="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><requests xmlns=""></RRTransaction>

Comment: Just check if your string starts with `[` or `{` than it's json, or if it starts with `<` its xml.

Comment: @Fussel - either of those could be a string that is not valid XML/JSON ... e.g. `[ I am not JSON` or `< this is fun`

Comment: Jaromanda X, in that case JSON also getting parsed to XML right?

Comment: @LavanyaKomarasamy - absolutely ..... not - JSON is JSON, XML is XML - they are not even distant cousins, they could marry and have normal children

Comment: @JaromandaX of cause, but if he knows his backend is sending correct stuff and just does not know if its in xml or json it would work.

Comment: but he states that the response can be `XML` `JSON` or `string` ... `[ this is not JSON` is a valid `string` - never assume to know what will happen in your code tomorrow

Comment: try {
            let xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); //is valid XML
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            // was not XML
            return false;
        }
i used the above code, but its returning true for json also...

Comment: that's because jQuery sux - but, with my test `$.parseXML(JSON.stringify({jquery:'sux'}))` it fails

Comment: can you try out solution suggested in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
   function GetInputType(response) {
    try {
      //try to parse via json 
      a = JSON.parse(response);
      return 'json type';
    } catch(e) {
     //try xml parsing 
     let parser = new DOMParser;
     var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response,"application/xml");
        if(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName == "parsererror")
           return 'string type';
        else 
           return 'xml type';
   }     
}
```

Comment: `parser.parseFromString` ... magic `parser` object is magic

Comment: @JaromandaX - not getting you but that is a way i found to parse string to xml

Comment: really ... so you have a magic `parser` variable in your browser? what is it? is it a `new DOMParser` you never had to create yourself? :p

Comment: I've added the missing piece for you - no need to thank me :D

Comment: Awesome! It's working perfect!! :D Thanks a lot friends :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382870/xml-syntax-highlighting-using-angular-2   anyone help me with this also?